# How to restore webview state

Tags: android, kotlin, android-webview

I am saving my state like this:

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    binding.webView.restoreState(savedInstanceState)
}

override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    binding.webView.saveState(outState)
}
```

**OnCreate**

```
shouldRestoreState = savedInstanceState?.let {
    true
} ?: false
bundle = savedInstanceState
```

**OnViewCreated**

```
    if (shouldRestoreState && bundle != null) {binding.webView.restoreState(bundle)} else { load normally }
```

It does working **BUT**

**A.** after few screen rotation, the screen goes black for few seconds and than loads show the page content

**B.** When I rotate the screen in youtube page, It load the screen but without any content.

What am I doing wrong with my code and how can I fix it?